# How can I download updates on Windows Server 2008 without installing them?

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'd like to download server updates on Windows Server 2008 but not actually install them until a later time. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start > Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Update > Change Settings > `Download updates but let me choose when to install them`

This will download new updates daily without installing them until you do so manually.

Comment: Perfect...knew it was something simple, just wasn't sure where it was. Thanks!